Show items with no data don't work if values are blank
I'm troubleshooting a Power Bi report and came across a table that needs to show the empty values.
enter image description here
If the columns Approved WTE, Filled WTE are empty, I still need to show it. The option Show items with no data don't work:
enter image description here
The model view is only one big raw data table. How can I fix that?
I tried to change the filter to include OR blank but still didn't work.

PowerBI has an option to show items with no data. To enable it right click on the filed and tick "show items with no data"
Screen below shows where to tick the option
